# UNIX sleep is sleeping more than it should on Android

Tags: android, linux, bash, ubuntu

I wanted to make a simple bash script, but noticed that `sleep` is not working properly.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
echo $(date)

sleep 1
done
```

Output of this script is:

```
Thu Jul 9 14:45:19 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:25 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:27 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:31 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:39 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:41 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:44 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:45:54 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:46:12 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:46:22 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:46:43 UTC 2020
Thu Jul 9 14:47:06 UTC 2020
```

Also tried `read -t 1 -u 1` and the results are the same.

What could be the cause of this?

I should point out that I am running this script on Ubuntu 18.04 which is running on android device with the help of Linux Deploy app. Ubuntu seems to run smoothly.

Comment: `sleep` doesn't guarantee that it will only sleep the amount of time requested. It's strictly best-effort. It's not _documented_ to have any such guarantees, either. Don't assume that applications will do anything except what their documentation promises.

Comment: ...and on low-powered hardware, relying on "best-effort" means you can get substantial delays. Also, `echo $(date)` is very unnecessarily slow. Do you _really_ have actual bash? If so, and it's a new enough version to have the relevant support, `printf '%(%c)T\n' -1` is much faster. Even without that, just running `date` with no `echo` will be _slightly_ more efficient (but not much, since it's still starting a whole new copy of `/usr/bin/date` every time you just want to print a new value; but at least it's forking off a separate shell to have that shell run `/usr/bin/date`).

Comment: Also, Android has a bunch of tweaks intended to make it more battery-efficient that _intentionally_ trade against timer precision, especially for background tasks.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as "bash sleep". When you run `sleep` in bash, you get `/usr/bin/sleep` -- it's a UNIX tool, not part of bash, so it's your OS vendor who controls exactly what it is and how it behaves.

Comment: ...btw, if this is an Android system where you have a busybox-based `/bin/sh`, you might well be better off using that instead of `bash`, since busybox executables don't need to use an `execve()` call to start _other_ busybox executables. That means that on systems where `sleep` and `date` are also parts of busybox, they can be much more efficiently called by a busybox `/bin/sh` than they can be called by `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for these pointers. I tried what you said but that did not fix my problem. After some time of letting the script run it seems that the problem fixed itself and now restarting the script results in correct sleeping time.

Comment: I didn't say _anything_ above would fix your problem. `sleep` is _always_ best-effort. You can't fix that. Stock Android kernels _always_ prioritize battery life over precise timing for non-foreground tasks. You can't fix that either. But what the above proposals _do_ improve is the amount of CPU utilization per time through the loop.

Comment: ...I do wonder if your system was under load from other processes, and now it's not. That would explain the problem going away, and would also give you somewhere to look if/when it comes back later. "Best-effort" timing tends to be more precise when a system is idle, and (much, much) less when there are more processes ready to be scheduled for the CPU than there are available cores. (For that reason, inefficient code running anywhere on the system contributes to making the problem worse).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android stops/pauses execution of my background script](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221413/android-stops-pauses-execution-of-my-background-script)